# npm publish for Angular Library

Tags: angular, npm, package, publish

I have an 'ng library' with the lib, tester and e2e projects. When I run 'ng build' it packages all 3 projects under 'dist'. I need to publish only the lib project. I know that 'cd' to 'dist/lib' and 'npm publish' works but I don't have that option as our CI build only does 'npm publish' in project root. 
So my question is how to achieve publish from the root, for just the lib project?

Comment: Can you not run `npm publish <path-to-lib>` ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I can run 'npm publish <dir>' locally and I know that solution. But CI doesn't do that. It is an enterprise-wide CI and currently only supports running 'npm publish' at root. I am looking if there is some workaround -e.g. package.json parameters or a prepublish step that can help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rejoice my fellow devs! Finally, after 5 days of banging my head on this problem, we have a solution! This is still a 'workaround', as there is no clear way current 'npm' version (as of Feb'2019) supports defining a 'default' publish directory through package.json - that would have been ideal and simpler. So here goes -

**Solution**

run `ng build` for the `ng library` root project. This would generate the `dist` folder with the `library` project and `tester` project in it. Open `dist/your-library-project/package.json` - this is the package.json that `ng-packager` generates based on your library's package.json.

Copy the auto-generated attributes from `dist/your-library-project/package.json` to your root `/package.json`

> ```
> "main": "bundles/your-library-project.umd.js",
> "module": "fesm5/your-library-project.js",
> "es2015": "fesm2015/your-library-project.js",
> "esm5": "esm5/your-library-project.js",
> "esm2015": "esm2015/your-library-project.js",
> "fesm5": "fesm5/your-library-project.js",
> "fesm2015": "fesm2015/your-library-project.js",
> "typings": "your-library-project.d.ts",
> "metadata": "your-library-project.metadata.json",
> "sideEffects": false,
> "dependencies": {
> "tslib": "^1.9.0"
> }
> ```

Change all paths to be relative to root `package.json`. So

> "main": "bundles/your-library-project.umd.js",

becomes

> "main": "dist/your-library-project/bundles/your-library-project.umd.js",

This essentially tells `npm` that when it imports your library module into another app, the entry point is at `dist/your-library-project/bundles/your-library-project.umd.js` - which allows the webapps to import the module by:

```
import {YourLibraryModule} from 'your-library';
```

Also, depending on what other attributes are there in your root `package.json`, it may need further fixes. E.g. I had to get rid of all `dependencies` that were not directly used by `library` project. Plus turn libraries's `dependencies` into `peerDependencies` or `devDependencies` depending on what it was for. Also, the root Angular project `angular.json` had to be updated to remove `tester` project. I created another `angular.json` in `tester` project to make it an Angular app in itself, separate from `library` project - which does not get published.

With all these changes, I am finally able to run `npm publish` from the root of my project and publish only the `dist/your-library-project`. This is super important for me, as my CI server's 'Publish' step can only execute `npm publish` from project root. With these changes, I can publish just the `library` module even from project root. Sure, this is just a workaround/hack, but I am happy that it can be at least done. Happy Days!

Comment: Thank you. I don't get how this can be so complicated ...

Comment: Hope it helped you. You may upvote to help others with similar problem

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, but both will require changes to your CI script:

Option 1:

```
$ npm publish <path-to-lib-folder>
```

Option 2:

```
$ cd <path-to-lib-folder>
$ npm publish
```

Comment: As mentioned in original question, I am aware of this solution but CI server can only run 'npm publish' at root. No provision for passing <dir> to 'npm publish' or executing 'cd' as part of publish step unfortunately. Changing CI step is not an easy task in a large organisation such as the one I work for.

Comment: @Pat Then there is no answer to your question, unfortunately, as far as I'm aware.